# How to add folder in share in Active directory domian user in vmware

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vmware-server

I have `window 2008 server` as host OS.

Then in VirtualMachine i have server 2008 with AD installed with one domain

Now i have one laptop with XP and i have joined with that AD Domain.

NOw in MY original Host 2008 i have one movies folder which i want to share only with XP laptop client.

I have installed file services on AD but the problem is in that File services i can only see the Hard disc of Server not my Host 2008.

I tried adding network drive in VM 2008 server but that is not visible in File services

What should i do

The HOST 2008 is not connected to domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either connect it to the domain and share the folder or shared the folder via VMWare Workstation/Server from the host to the guest and get the guest to share it to the laptop.

Comment: i have shared the folder via vmware to guest server 2008 but it seems that i can't share it further from guest to another computer

Comment: Odd, should be fine, ok then try the first idea.